# Function doesBucketExist of amazon aws gives false result with bucket name contains .(dot)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am Using AWS api for Php. When I use doesBucketExist function and pass the bucket name as abc.def, it gives false result. But this bucket is present in S3. It is working fine with other buckets having simple name like wxyz.Basically it cannot take . (dot) in the name of bucket. So how I will read abc.def bucket.

Comment: I got the same problem with you

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem occur due to PHP api. Download API from this link. It will solve your problem.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php